# pre-selected items in CActiveForm->checkBoxList in Yii

Tags: yii, selecteditem, checkboxlist

I have two arrays. One is **$categories** which contains all categories retrieved from my db and the other is **$preSelectedCategories** which contains the categories that needs to be pre-selected in my check box list when my form is loaded. I tried to do this:

```
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'category_id'); ?>
<?php echo $form->checkBoxList($model, 'category_id', $categories, $preSelectedCategories, array('multiple'=>true)); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model,'category_id'); ?>
```

But I did not succeed. Could anyone help me solve this problem? Thanks!

Edit: I already knew that using **CHtml::checkBoxList** could help, but what I want here is to use **CActiveForm::checkBoxList** because I am using a model to validate the checkbox list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to use [`CHtml::activeName`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#activeName-detail) to get an appropriate name for the input and pass it to `CHtml::checkBoxList`, like others have suggested.

Another option that is, in my opinion, more appropriate would be to add those `category_id`s you want pre-checked to the model in the controller, before rendering the form (only when it's a GET request). Then you wouldn't need to modify the form at all.

Comment: I do not know how to set the pre-checked `category_id`s in the controller. Could you give me an example?

Comment: Have you tried `$model->category_id = array_merge((array)$model->category_id, $preSelectedCategories);` before you call `$this->render();` in the controller action? I have no idea how you're saving these values and how that field is defined on your model, so this might not work, but it's the general idea. (Add the controller and model code to your question if it doesn't work and you need more  help.)

Comment: Thanks, your solution works pretty well! I forgot that we could set values for model attributes before rendering the view, my bad!

Answer (score 2):

You can easily pre-populate a checkBoxList with selected items, it takes an array of selected keys in its second parameter.

```
$selected_keys = array_keys(CHtml::listData( $model->books, 'id' , 'id'));

echo CHtml::checkBoxList('Author[books][]', $selected_keys, $books);
```

Please see full example here, on my blog:

http://scriptbaker.com/how-to-make-yii-checkboxlist-selected/

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product. I have added the disclosure for you; please be sure to take care of this yourself in the future!

Comment: @AndrewBarber thanks for your comment, you mean if I quote a URL from my own blog I should explicitly tell that its from my blog? and add words like "on my blog"?

Answer (score 1):

`CHtml::actviceCheckBoxList` (CActiveForm::checkBoxList that you use is wrapper to it) have such syntax

```
 public static function activeCheckBoxList($model,$attribute,$data,$htmlOptions=array())
```

If you want to manually set pre-selected values - you shoul use CHtml::checkBoxList instead

```
public static function checkBoxList($name,$select,$data,$htmlOptions=array())
```

Here is the piece of CHtml class reference

```
 * @param string $name name of the check box list. You can use this name to retrieve
     * the selected value(s) once the form is submitted.
     * @param mixed $select selection of the check boxes. This can be either a string
     * for single selection or an array for multiple selections.
     * @param array $data value-label pairs used to generate the check box list.
     * Note, the values will be automatically HTML-encoded, while the labels will not.
```

Comment: I already knew that CHtml::checkBoxList could help, but the problem is that I want to use CActiveForm::checkBoxList so that I could validate the field using my model's rules.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
$categories = array(1,2,3);
$preSelectedCategories = array(1=>true,2=>true); // use this way 
echo CHtml::checkBoxList('category_id',$preSelectedCategories,$categories); 
?>
```

Try this I have tried, it runs successfully.

Comment: Your solution does not work. As far as I know, `checkAllLast` is of boolean type which determines whether the check all checkbox should be put at the end of the checkbox list. What I want is to have some checkboxes automatically checked when the page is loaded.

Comment: Sorry for the untested reply, I have corrected the answer and it works fine.

Comment: Now you're just repeating sl4mmer's suggestion.

Comment: thanks, your solution works now but what I really want is to use `CActive::checkBoxList` instead of `CHtml::checkBoxList` since I am using a model to validate it.

Answer (score 1):

remove $preSelectedCategories variable.
Set $model->category_id to be an array which holds the selected checkbox values.

```
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'category_id'); ?>
<?php 
$model->category_id = array('value1','value2');
echo $form->checkBoxList($model, 'category_id', $categories, array('multiple'=>true)); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model,'category_id'); ?>
```

You should try this but I did not tested this.

Answer (score 1):

Populate your attribute with an array before displaying it on the form.

In the controller:

```
public function actionUpdate($id) {

  $model=$this->loadModel($id);

  //For example
  $categories = array(0=>'Option One',1=>'Option Two',2=>'Option Three');
  $preSelectedCategories = array(1,2);

  //Magic here
  $model->category_id = $preSelectedCategories;

  if(isset($_POST['NameOfModel']) {
    //category_id reset with incoming form data...
  }
  ...
  $this->render('update',array('model'=>$model,'categories'=>$categories));
}
```

In the view, in your form:

```
echo $form->checkBoxList($model,'category_id',$categories);
```

Untested since I modified it here... adapted from Bootstrap extension's form widgets.

Answer (score 1):

Most of yii members having same issue, so here more sweet code with clear explanation.

First you need to find your pre-selected categories like -

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->select = 'category_id as id';
$criteria->condition = 'userid = :userid';
$criteria->params = array(':userid' => Yii::app()->user->id);

//store pre-selected id into variable  - $selected_keys
$selected_keys = array_keys(CHtml::listData(MyCategory::model()->findAll($criteria), 'id', 'id'));
```

Now generate whole category list, like -

```
$list = CHtml::listData(Categories::model()->findAll(array('order'=>'id')), 'id', 'category_name');

//htmlOptions for class and others elements
$htmlOptions = array('template' => '{input}{label}', 'separator'=>'', 'class'=>'in-checkbox', 'multiple'=>true, 'checked'=>'checked');
```

View part -

```
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'Category', array('class'=>'col-md-3 control-label')); ?>
<?php $model->Category = $selected_keys; //assign pre-selected list to Category list
      echo $form->checkBoxList($model, 'Category', $list, $htmlOptions); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model, 'Category'); ?>
```

Try this, work great..