# Yii activeCheckBoxList

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

I have a strange probem

In AR model,  Gift i have many_many relation with categories

```
              'categories'=>array(self::MANY_MANY, 'GiftCategory',
                        'tbl_category_gift(gift_id, category_id)'),
```

And when i call     $gift->categories   it returns active record objects, and in database i see that values is stored correctly

But when i write

```
        <? echo $form->checkBoxList($model, "categories", GiftCategory::listData()); ?>
```

In my checkboxlist only 1 value is selected if model have categories, i dont understand wtf is it, please, help :)

PROBLEM: Yii activeCheckBoxList displaying only 1 checked (only first)

Comment: Read this [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577231/pre-selected-items-in-cactiveform-checkboxlist-in-yii

I am sure you will find out answer here.

Comment: Show your GiftCategory::listData() implementation

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because, in the words of the [Yii creator Qiang](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/3489-php-error-object-of-class-group-could-not-be-converted-to-int-when-i-try-to-use-chtml/page__view__findpost__p__18966):

> ...in activeListBox(), the second parameter should be an attribute
>   name, not a relation name. In your case, you may need to declare a new
>   property to store the selections.

I believe the same thing applies to activeCheckBoxList.

The way I solved this was as follows (this blog post was helpful [Retrieving selected checkbox items in yii](http://www.tipstank.com/2010/07/19/retrieving-selected-checkbox-items-in-yii/))

**Add index option to your relation**

```
'categories' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 
    'Category', 'post_category(post_id, category_id)','index'=>'id'),
```

**Add a property to your model**

```
public $selectedCategoryIds
```

**Populate this attribute in afterFind**

```
public function afterFind()
{
    parent::afterFind();
    $this->selectedCategoryIds = array_keys($this->categories);
}
```

**Use this new "attribute in your view**

```
<? echo $form->checkBoxList($model, "selectedCategoryIds", GiftCategory::listData()); ?>
```

In order to properly handle updating this data see Larry Ullman's article [Handling Related Models in Yii Forms](http://www.larryullman.com/2010/08/10/handling-related-models-in-yii-forms/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
echo CHtml::activeCheckBoxList($model, 'categories',
        CHtml::listData(GiftCategory::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'title'),
        array('checkAll' => ' Select All'));
?>
```